# Posting an uploaded file via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to post a file that I upload through ajax. My file uploading and validation works without javascript when the simple post is used. But when javascript is turned on and the form has to be submitted through ajax, it doesn't work. I believe it is a problem with the way I am handling the file upload through ajax but I can't figure out what the problem is.

JQuery (ajax here):

```
    var first_name = $('#first-name').val();
    var last_name = $('#last-name').val();
    var school = $('#school-register').val();
    var formData = new FormData('#transcript');
    var url="post.php";

    $.ajax({

           type: 'POST',
           url: url,
           data: {first_name: first_name,last_name: last_name,school:school,file:formData}
    })
       .done(function(response_data)
        {
                alert(response_data);
        });
       return false;
```

HTML Form:

```
    <form id="animate1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="post.php">

    <input id="first-name" name="first_name" type="text" value="" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="100">
    <input id="last-name" name="last_name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="100">
    <input id="school-register" name="school" type="text" value="" placeholder="High School" maxlength="100">

    <label for="transcript">Transcript</label><input type="file" id="transcript" name="file">
```

PHP:

```
if ((isset($_POST['first_name'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['first_name'])) > 0)) 
{
$first_name = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['first_name']));
} 
else 
{
$msg = "Student's first name required!";
$_SESSION['msg'] = $msg;
$url = "noJS.php";
header("Location: $url");
exit;
}
```

Similarly for the last name and school name.

PHP for the file:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
        $fInfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mime = finfo_file($fInfo,$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        $attach = false;
        switch($mime)
        {
        case 'application/pdf':
        $attach = true;
        break;
        default:
            $msg = "Wrong file format of transcript (please upload a PDF file)!";
            $_SESSION['msg'] = $msg;
            $url = "noJS.php";
            header("Location: $url");
            exit;
    }
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
        $_FILES['file']['name']);
}
```

Comment: Add the additional fields to the formdata and send the formdata as the only data.

Comment: It's harder than you think. Some reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: @KevinB the thing is my entire form is much bigger and complex, this is just a part of it. Is the way i used incorrect?

Comment: Yes, formData consists of key/value pairs, passing it as the value of a key doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, do you need this code to work in IE9 or less? because formData isn't supported in IE9 and older.

Comment: @KevinB no only after ie9, how would I include all the fields in formdata?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FFormData